# Nestjs - use multiple models in a service

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

I have a Nestjs and MongoDB application.

`auth.module.ts` -

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

`auth.service.ts` -

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  // Inject User model into AuthService
  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>) {}

  getUser(username: string) {
    const user = this.userModel.find({ name: username });
    return user;
  }

  
}
```

I have a UserSchema created using `@nestjs/mongoose` and `mongoose`.

According to the docs, when I import a schema using `MongooseModule` in a Module, that schema is available to use in that particular module only.

What if I want access to multiple models in my module and service? Is there a way for that?

How do I Inject multiple models into a service?

Answer (score 11):

here is the solution:-

auth.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
       { name: 'User', schema: UserSchema },
       { name: 'Comment', schema: CommentSchema }
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

auth.service.ts

```js
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<IUser>,
    @InjectModel('Comment') private readonly CommentModel: Model<IComment>
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: is the '=' intentional?

Comment: @vaibhavdeep that was a typo